# Question listing formatting bug

Tags: bug, design, formatting

I think this is a formatting bug. Can be seen for instance on

https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/formatting?page=2&sort=unanswered&pagesize=50

[image]

Comment: i suspect there's a width limit, and 3 digits kicks it over the limit.

Comment: @barbarabeeton Seems so. Still, it's IMHO a bug.

Comment: i have sadly concluded that there's no accounting for design decisions here.

Comment: I see the break for two digit numbers as well, so i never wondered. Rather, i would swap the words in your picture. What you tagged *good* is the one sticking out. All others have the word (votes/answers/views) below the number.